# What's the best way of figuring out where traffic is coming from with pfSense?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, pfsense

My home network is run by a pfSense router. So far I haven't had any trouble with it. My home network includes some people(via wireless) outside of my home. I've been having some bandwidth abuse being done recently and basically want to cut them off of internet when I want to.

My problem is I can't figure out which MAC address or IP address(and all hostnames are empty for them) is taking all the bandwidth. What's the best way to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use pftop from the shell command on console or ssh into the device after enabling ssh server in system -> advanced.